# Can't recover data on honor 5x Android 6.0.1

Tags: data-recovery, huawei-u8860

I have done factory reset of my honor 5x Android 6.0.1 by mistake. This phone is rooted and I have tried disk digger pro, desktop applications like easeus recovery via USB debugging. It detects only recent data but not deleted one.

1. I have not overwritten any data ;
2. Phone did not has encryped storage before reset ;
3. It has fingerprint lock before factory reset ;
4. I want to recover phone storage data ;
5. PC applications unable to find any deleted data after scanning all sectors on phone storage.

I have done recovery on Android 5.0 lenovo s850 and it was fine so I have recovery experience.

- Has factory reset cleared all sectors ?
- Does Android 6.0.1 not support recovery ?
- Should I rollback to 5.0 and then try ?
- Any method available ?

Answer (score 1):

Android factory reset will erase **ALL DATA**. The chances of you recovering the data are very slim.

If you didn't erase the internal SD Card, you may have your files.

But all game/app progress and data are gone.

Comment: Is Factory reset on honor set every bit of remaining storage to logic 0 or 1 bcz I have recovered lenovo phone data after factory reset.

Comment: factory reset erases everything

Comment: I know it erases everything but indeed on other devices it removes only files and folders references written on some area of storage thats the reason we can recover most of storages after a full high level format or erasing everything from a storage.

Comment: if you read my answer, if your phone has an internal SD card, you may have unchecked the erase checkbox for that section, keeping the data. But no matter what, the game/app progress and data are gone

Comment: Oh..let me tell you I have done hard reset from recovery not from android setting menu.